# ¿Por qué findByIdAndUpdate no actualiza el documento?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo mi problema con la siguiente función:

```
export function updateLine(req: Request, res: Response) {
    if (!req.params.id || !req.body) return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Client has not sent params' });
    Line.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, async (err, lineUpdated) => {
        console.log("req.params.id", req.params.id)
        console.log("lineUpdated", lineUpdated)
        console.log("req.body", req.body)
        if (err) return res.status(409).send({ message: 'Internal error, probably error with params' });
        if (!lineUpdated) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Document not found' });
        if (req.params.id !== lineUpdated.id) await Key.updateMany({ 'line': req.params.id }, { 'line': lineUpdated._id }).exec(err => {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Key Internal Server Error' });
        });
        return res.status(200).send({ data: lineUpdated });
    });
}
```

Lo que intento hacer es únicamente actualizar el documento `req.params.id` con lo que contiene `req.body`.

La respuestas a los console.log() que se muestran son los siguientes:

```
req.params.id ACCSEH
lineUpdated {
  _id: 'ACCSEH',
  name: 'Accesorios (SEH)',
  started: 2020-04-21T20:25:10.395Z,
  __v: 0
}
req.body { id: 'ACCSEJ', name: 'Accesorios (SEH)' }
```

¿Estoy haciendo algo mal?

Ya sé que **lineUpdated** me devolverá la función antes del cambio. Me refiero a que cuando hago la consulta para ver el cambio, no ha cambiado nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás intentando actualizar el campo `_id` de una documento en una colección de MongoDB. No puedes hacer dicha actualización usando el método `findByIdAndUpdate`.

La razón es sencilla:

El campo `_id` en MongoDB es como el equivalente a un campo `Primary Key` en SQL. No se puede *actualizar* el campo `_id`, tal como no puedes actualizar un campo `PK` en SQL directamente.

Te recomiendo nunca alterar el mismo, si necesitas identificar tu documento con un valor distinto al proporcionado por MongoDB para el campo `_id` (el cual es un tipo `ObjectId`), puedes crear un campo adicional, para que puedas realizar este tipo de actualizaciones, y puedes añadir una restricción tipo `Unique` sobre dicho campo.

Ahora, una de las cosas que puedes hacer para modificar un documento alterando el campo `_id`, es simplemente insertar un nuevo documento (el que tiene el nuevo `_id`) y una vez insertado, eliminar el documento con el `_id` anterior.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const line = new Line(req.body);
line._id = req.body.id; // aqui establezco el nuevo id sobre un nuevo documento
line.save((error, result) => {
  if(error) {
    //manejo del error (no se salvó el documento nuevo)
  }
  // podemos ver documento nuevo creado
  console.log(result);
  //borramos el documento antiguo
  Line.remove({_id: req.params.id}, (error, result) => {
    if(error) {
      // manejo del error
    }
    // vemos cuantos documentos fueron afectados (1 o 0).
    console.log(result.deletedCount);
    if(!result.deletedCount) {
      // no se eliminó ningún documento
    }
    // todo fue ok
  });
});
```

De esta forma podrías simular una actualización sobre el campo `_id`. Pero mi recomendación es que no alteres tus documentos mediante esta forma, es innecesario y pierdes las características intrínsecas de MongoDB.

Puedes consultar la documentación del método [`remove()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove)

Comment: Oh rayos, el problema es que antes me servía, no se porque apenas ahorita no ;n; creo que era porque cambiaba el name. Rayos, tengo que cambiar ahora toda la estructura de mi proyecto ;n;

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, findByIdAndUpdate() se toma su tiempo, te hace falta el async/await cambia tu código por esto:

```
export async function updateLine(req:Request, res:Response): Promise<Response> { 
    //if...
    const { name } = req.body;
    const lineUpdated = await Line.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, name, {new: true}, (err, lineUpdated) => { //validaciones });
    return res.status(200).send({ data: lineUpdated });
   }
```

Comment: Este cambio que realiza?

Answer (score -1):

Sumando a lo que respondieron más arriba, podrías crear un index "generico" por así decirlo para simular un objectId con mongoose

```
 await Collection.create({
        index: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toString(),
        ...: ...,
 });
```